# Partition function for dipolar dielectrics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dielectric, partition-function

How can you write the partition function for non-polar and polar dielectric materials?  For dipolar dielectric materials we can easily write partition function;  it is proportional to $\exp(-\beta\mu E \cos \theta)$ where $\mu$ is the dipole moment and $E$ is applied field.  Is there a similar expression for non-polar dielectrics or polar dielectrics?

Comment: For the terminology, what's the difference between a "dipolar" dielectric (I don't think it's standard) and a polar dielectric?

Comment: Okay. Yes, you're correct. Actually, i was trying to calculate why ionic polarizability doesn't depend on the temperature? Dipolar polarizability do depend on the temperature and that we can see by calculating the partition function and then average magnetic dipole moment or electric dipole moment. So, similarly i was trying to see whether i can proof that the ionic or electronic polarizability doesn't depend on the temperature by the same maths or not?. That's why  i used dipolar dielectric materials.